# In Python create a table with categories and ranges based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in a table that looks like this:

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'cat':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
              'num':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]
             })
```

It's just an example. I am not required to use pandas. The point is, that input data will come in a table format.

I need two separate results:

**(1) The First Table:**

| Cat | MIN | MAX |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 8 |
| A | 12 | 14 |
| B | 9 | 11 |
| B | 15 | 21 |

**(2) The Second Table:**

| Cat | ranges |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1-8; 12-14 |
| B | 9-11; 15-21 |

So far I tried to do this with pandas but then I've read that iterating over df might not be a good idea. Here above it's just an example but the actual df will have from 1K to 10K+ rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First aggregate `min/max` by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with helper `Series` g for consecutive `cat` values, last sorting by `cat` by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
g = input_data['cat'].ne(input_data['cat'].shift()).cumsum()
df = (input_data.groupby([g, 'cat'], as_index=False)
                .agg(MIN=('num','min'), MAX=('num','max'))
                .sort_values('cat', ignore_index=True))
print (df)
  cat  MIN  MAX
0   A    1    8
1   A   12   14
2   B    9   11
3   B   15   21
```

For second ouput use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) with aggregate `join`:

```
df1 = (df['MIN'].astype(str).str.cat(df['MAX'].astype(str), sep='-')
                .groupby(df['cat']).agg('; '.join)
                .reset_index(name='ranges'))
print(df1)
  cat       ranges
0   A   1-8; 12-14
1   B  9-11; 15-21
```

Answer (score 2):

For the first dataframe, you can create a new group each time the `cat` row is not equal to the previous then use aggregate functions. For the second one, concatenate `MIN` and `MAX` columns then group by `Cat` then join them:

```
df1 = (input_data.groupby(df['cat'].ne(df['cat'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False)
         .agg(Cat=('cat', 'first'), MIN=('num', 'min'), MAX=('num', 'max')))

df2 = (df1.assign(ranges=df1['MIN'].astype(str) + '-' + df1['MAX'].astype(str))
          .groupby('Cat', as_index=False)['ranges'].apply('; '.join))
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
  Cat  MIN  MAX
0   A    1    8
1   B    9   11
2   A   12   14
3   B   15   21

>>> df2
  Cat       ranges
0   A   1-8; 12-14
1   B  9-11; 15-21
```